# Sum the minutes of multiple columns and the hours of another column and hours to a new column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that is the sum of multiple rows in Postgres

Query ------------------------------------------------------------------

```
select 
    ...
    sum(i.cantidad) as totalHoras, 
    sum(i.minutos) as totalMinutos,
    ...
```

Result   -------------------------------------------------------------------

```
totalHoras  |   toltaMinutos

152         |      450

160         |      0

163         |      90


I could in the same statement, divide the minutes by 60 and add them at the same time to the hours, and put them in a new column called "total"

152 + (450/60) = 159,5
160 + (0/60)   = 160  <-- If the minutes are 0, check that it does not divide
163 + (90/60)  = 164,5


I use postgres version 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
select 
    ...
    sum(i.cantidad) as totalHoras, 
    sum(i.minutos) as totalMinutos,
    sum(i.cantidad) + 1.0*sum(i.minutos)/60 as total,
    ...
```

Comment: You must understand the difference between integer and floating point arithmetic.  Integer arithmetic always truncates any remainder, thus in your original formula *(90/60) = 1*, floating point does not truncate fractional values so *(90/60.0) = 1.5*. The solution proposed by @Zalaria works because the *1.0\*sum...* forces that sub-expression to be floating point which in turn forces the whole expression to be floating point. However be careful of floating point. For example if sum(i.minutos) comes to 20 then the result will be something like nnn.3333333333. You may need to handle that.